# Catalog Price Rule not showing "Discount" value in cart totals

Tags: cart, catalog-price-rules, promotions, price-rules

I have a site with a Catalog Price rule and a Shopping Cart Price Rule.

If you use a Shopping Cart Price Rule, there is a "Discount" row added to the basket totals summary showing the discount label and the value discounted.

If you use a Catalog Price rule, the unit price/total is discounted but you don't get a "Discount" row added to the basket totals summary. On the product pages I am seeing "Original Price/Special Price" but it's almost like once you click through to the cart Magento no longer recognises that the product is discounted and thinks the new price is the original price.

For example, a 50% off catalog price rule to a £10 product. On the product page this shows as "Original price: £10" and "Special Price: £5". This is fine. But on basket...

**Expected results (same as Shopping Cart):**

```
Unit Price: £10.00
Subtotal: £10.00
Discount: -£5.00
Grand Total: £5.00
```

**Current results:**

```
Unit Price: £5.00
Subtotal: £5.00
(No discount row)
Grand Total: £5.00
```

Is this expected behaviour or do I have a problem somewhere? Thanks very much.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's difference between shopping cart rules and catalog rules, If you use Shopping cart then on Product View page you will see original price, and in shopping cart you can apply discount code, and get your row "Discount". In your case,(Catalog price rules) it's already discounted, that's why you dont see Discount row in shopping cart. That's why your current result is correct and expected

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought - that it was default behaviour - but just wanted confirmation.